# Ext, obstruction for what is Ext?, Tor is an obstruction for being flat

Tags: modules, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence, projective-module, flatness

Let $M,N$ be in $R-\mathbb{Mod}$.

[Here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~znorwood/partiii/files/commalgnotes2apage.pdf)
on page 28 is written

Think of $\mathbb{Tor}$ as describing how far $N$ is from being flat.

> Now, for what $\mathbb{Ext}$ measures how far is $N$ from?

Comment: How have you defined Ext?

Comment: [See here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~znorwood/partiii/files/commalgnotes2apage.pdf)
on page 28, the r.h.s. (Dually via Hom functor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functor $\mathrm{Tor}^R(N, -)$ is the derived functor of $N \otimes_R -$, so $\mathrm{Tor}^R(N, -)$ is the zero functor if and only if $N \otimes_R -$ is an exact functor.  We call $N$ for which $N \otimes_R -$ is exact *flat* modules.

The functor $\mathrm{Ext}_R(N, -)$ is the derived functor of $\mathrm{Hom}(N, -)$ and modules for which this functor is exact are the projective modules, so $\mathrm{Ext}_R(N, -)$ measures how far a module is from being projective.

The functor $\mathrm{Ext}_R(-, N)$ is the derived functor of $\mathrm{Hom}(-, N)$ and modules for which this functor is exact are the injective modules, so $\mathrm{Ext}_R(-, N)$ measures how far a module is from being injective.

Comment: You really mean "...is the zero funcotr if and only if $N\otimes_R-$ is **right** exact funcotr", right?

Comment: Also, you have reversed the order of modules $M$ and $N$: in the paper on page 28 there is written $\mathrm{Tor}^R(M,N)$ and not $\mathrm{Tor}^R(N,M)$, and **only** then it measures how far is $N$ from being flat.With your notation it measures how far is $N$ from being projective.

Comment: No, I don't mean right exact.  Tensoring with a module is *always* right exact.  Tor is nonzero if and only if tensoring with that module is exact.

Comment: Also, for a commutative ring $R$ $\mathrm{Tor}^R(N, M)$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Tor}^R(M, N)$.  For a non-commutative ring whether $N$ must appear on the left or right depends on whether it is a right module or a left module.  In either case Tor is measuring the failure of flatness, not the failure of projectivity.  Though projective modules *are* flat so you could consider the failure to be flat as also a failure to be projective.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M,N$ be $R$-modules.

$Ext^{i}_{R}(M,N)=0$ for $i>0$ if $M$ is projective or $N$ is injective, this combined with the fact that these are the derived functors of $Hom$ functors makes me conclude that it is a measure of how far a module is from being projective or injective.